# How to get the last output and full sequence of LSTM or GRU in Keras at same time?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

In Keras, when using `LSTM` or `GRU`, if I set `return_sequences=False`, I will get the last output; if I set `return_sequences=True`, I will get the full sequence; but how to get them both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the last timestep returned when `return_sequences=True` is equivalent to the output of LSTM layer when `return_sequences=False`:

```py
lstm_out_rs = LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(x)
lstm_out_rs[:,-1]  # this is the last timestep of returned sequence 

lstm_out = LSTM(..., return_sequences=False)(x)
```

`lstm_out_rs[:,-1]` and `lstm_out` are equivalent to each other. Therefore, to have them both you can use a `Lambda` layer:

```py
lstm_out_rs = LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(x)
out = Lambda(lambda t: [t, t[:,-1]])(lstm_out_rs)

# out[0] is all the outputs, out[1] is the last output
```